# How to calculate interest javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to create a function that returns the money I have after x years of interest.

```js
var calculateInterest = function(total, year, rate) {
  (var interest = rate / 100 + 1;
  return parseFloat((total * Math.pow(interest, year)).toFixed(4))
}

console.log(calculateInterest(915, 13, 2));
```

I'm not getting it to work and I'm stuck!
Any advice?

Comment: why do you have an opening bracket in front of "var"? (second line)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, it's helpful to let us know what exactly is stuck -- are you getting any errors, a null result, or something else?

Comment: From a financial angle, how is the interest compounded? For example most mortgages compound monthly because you pay monthly. Current accounts (and maybe credit cards) can compound daily. If you get a slightly different answer than the one you were expecting, it could be this. Or the way that days are counted for the interest (which varies subtly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. You don't need parentheses around `var interest`:

```js
var calculateInterest = function(total, year, rate) {
  var interest = rate / 100 + 1;
  return parseFloat((total * Math.pow(interest, year)).toFixed(4));
}

var answer = calculateInterest(915, 13, 2);
console.log(answer);
```

I'd recommend cleaning it up a little to:

```js
var calculateInterest = function(total, years, ratePercent, roundToPlaces) {
  var interestRate = ((ratePercent / 100) + 1);
  return (total * Math.pow(interestRate, years)).toFixed(roundToPlaces);
}

var answer = calculateInterest(915, 13, 2, 2);
console.log(answer);
```

You don't need `parseFloat()` if the variable is already a number (it's needed when you're parsing from a string, which is not the case here). I am adding a parameter to specify how many decimal places to round to is useful so you can control the output of the function.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atbzavrv/1/)